# A question in Exponential Generating Function

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let $h_n$ be the number of ways to split a group of n children into nonempty groups,
have each group form a circle, and then have these circles form a circle. Find the
exponential generating function H(x) of the sequence $h_n$. Two arrangements are
considered identical if each child has the same left neighbor in them, and each cycle
has the same left neighbor in them.

Let $a_n$ be th number of ways to form a group of n persons to circle. Then $a_n$ = (n-1)!.
Using $a_n$ find A(x). Since the n can be split into any number of groups , then we have to consider the generating function 1/(1-A(x)). Bt since the circles again form circles I know we have to some composition here . Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the problem is that we are asked to find the EGF of the number of ways to form a cycle of cycles.  The EGF of the number of ways to arrange $n$ objects in a cycle (i.e. a circle), is
$$f(z) = \ln \left( \frac{1}{1-z} \right)$$
so the EGF of a cycle of cycles is simply
$$f(f(z)) = \ln \left( \frac{1}{1-\ln \left( \frac{1}{1-z} \right)} \right)$$
Using Mathematica to expand the series, it starts out
$$f(f(z)) = \frac{1}{1!} z + \frac{2}{2!} z^2 + \frac{7}{3!} z^3 + \frac{35}{4!} z^4 + \frac{228}{5!} z^5 + \dots$$